# Instantiate but I want floats

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently instantiating a GetTile prefab using Vector3 but I am trying to plot it in a hex grid so I want Vector3 to output floats. ie I want to be able to divide y by 2 and get 1.5, 2 , 2.5 etc. but it can only output int values (1,2,2).

For context this is the code:

```
public void Draw(Cell[,] state) /// this is creates the board by using the tiles given from GetTile and SetTile
    {
        int width = state.GetLength(0);
        int height = state.GetLength(1);

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                Cell cell = state[x, y];
                //tilemap.SetTile(cell.position, GetTile(cell));
                Instantiate(GetTile(cell),new Vector3(x,y,0), Quaternion.identity) ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a workaround for this? Or this because of the nature of Instantiate. Honestly lost so would appreciate the help.

Comment: We don't know what a ```Vector3``` is in your code. Is it from a library? If so, which one?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the tag. Just updated it thanks for letting me know. Vector3 is under the UnityEngine library apologizes for the confusion.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 4):

[Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) receives `Vector3` and it [supports floats](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-ctor.html).

If I'm reading your issue correctly, you're trying to divide the value by 2. Since `x` and `y` are defined in the for loop as `int`, you are getting int values.

So instead of dividing by `2`, try dividing by `2f`, e.g.

`Instantiate(GetTile(cell),new Vector3(x / 2f, y / 2f, 0), Quaternion.identity);`

Comment: this or just divide `new Vector3(x, y, 0) / 2` in which case there is only float division anyway